# Homotopy relative to closed set

Tags: general-topology

Let $f,g:M\to N$ be two maps where $N$ is contractible. Suppose $f=g$ on a closed set $A\subset M$. I know that $f\simeq g$, but can we have a homotopy such that $f\simeq g\ {\rm rel}\ A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general not. Let $M = N$ be the comb space $C = \{ (x, y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1] \mid y = 0 \text{ or } x \in \{ 0 \} \cup \{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb N \} \}$. This space is contractible. Let $f = id$ and $g(x,y) \equiv (0,1)$. These maps are not homotopic rel. $A = \{ (0,1) \}$. To see this, assume there exists a homotopy $H : f  \simeq g$ which is stationary on $A$. Let $U = C \cap [0,1] \times (0,1]$ which is an open  neighborhood of $(0,1)$. By continuity and compactness of $A$ there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $(0,1)$ such that $H(V \times I) \subset U$. $V$ contains a point $x_n = (1/n,1)$. Then $H$ gives a path in $U$ from $x_n = H(x_n,0)$ to $(0,1) = H(x_n,1)$. This is impossible because these points belong to different components of $U$.

However, if $A \hookrightarrow M$ is a *cofibration*, then it is true.

Comment: What about $M$ and $N$ being smooth manifolds?

Comment: You should ask this as a new question!