# Homotopy relative to a closed set for smooth manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

In the problem [Homotopy relative to closed set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3276776/homotopy-relative-to-closed-set/3277057?noredirect=1#comment6741448_3277057), I asked whether 2 maps $f,g:M\to N$ from $M$ to $N$ where $N$ is contractible, such that $f=g$ on some closed set $A\subset M$ are homotopic relative to $A$.

@Paul Frost gives a counterexample with $M=N=$ the comb space. Actually, when I asked the previous question, I was having smooth manifolds and smooth maps in mind. So now I want to know whether this is true or not? That is to say,

> Let $f,g:M\to N$ be two smooth maps between smooth manifolds $M$, $N$ where $N$ is contractible. Suppose $f=g$ on a closed set $A\subset M$ , does it follow that $f\simeq g\ {\rm rel}\ A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Every manifold is an ANR (= absolute neighborhood retract for metrizable spaces, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retract). Each contractible ANR is an AR (= absolute retract for metrizable spaces). So let us prove a more general result:

Let $f,g : M\to N$ be two maps from a metrizable space $M$ to an AR $N$ such that $f=g$ on some closed set $A\subset M$. Then $f,g$ are homotopic relative to $A$.

The proof is very simple. The set $B = M \times \{0,1\} \cup A \times I$ is closed in $M \times I$. Define $\phi : B \to N$ by $\phi(a,t) = f(a)$, $\phi(m,0) = f(m)$ and $\phi(m,1) = g(m)$. This is a contiuous map. Since $N$ is an AR, it has a continuous Extension $H : M \times I \to N$. This is the desired homotopy.

What I am not sure is whether you can always get a  smooth homotopy.

Comment: I think I need some time to get familiar with the language of AR and figure out why every manifold is an ANR as well as contractible ANR is AR. But your answer makes sense to me when I began reading Borsuk "Theory of retracts". Thanks a lot. By the way, continuous homotopy between smooth maps can always be replaced by a smooth one due to Whitney approximation theorem (see thm 3.4 of http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/18F-Manifolds/Notes/Lec10.pdf).

Comment: @Y.Guo I am not sure whether you can get a smooth homotopy rel. $A$. To apply the Whitney Approximation Theorem for Continuous Maps you need the map $\phi$ to be smooth on $B$ which requires a smooth extension at least to a small neighborhood of $B$.